# Visual Studio 2022 and .net update issues for Azure Function App

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I have been using Visual Studio 2019 for my Azure Function App. I recently updated to version 2022, I then uninstalled 2019.

I am getting the following errors now:

```
 1>CodeaApi -> G:\AVR_Project\Codea App\Codea Azure Function App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\bin\CodeaApi.dll
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.0.0' (x64) was not found.
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :   - The following frameworks were found:
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :       6.0.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : 
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : 
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : The specified framework can be found at:
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :   - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error :
    1>C:\Users\asf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.6\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : Metadata generation failed.
    1>Done building project "CodeaApi.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Do I need to install version 3.0.1 to make it compatible with Azure Function Apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can resolve this by installing [.NET Core 3.1 SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/wiki/Known-issues#net-core-31-dependency),

> When targeting Azure Functions 3.0, by default, the .NET Core 3.1 SDK
> is required on the machine building the project.

Comment: Thanks, It seems that when I uninstalled VS 2019 .net core was also uninstalled.